# Filter the default route, but accept all other routes

Tags: bgp, brocade

I have a BGP session where the other participant is advertising the default route in addition to a number of small prefixes.

I want to filter out the default, but accept those other prefixes.

I've tried to use:

`ip prefix-list no-default-route  seq 5 deny 0.0.0.0/0`

In combination with:

`neighbor 10.4.1.1 prefix-list no-default-route in`

But that ends up filtering all of the smaller prefix routes as well.

Is there a way I can filter out the default, but accept all other prefixes?

Comment: Remember, prefix-lists (just like access-lists) have an implicit deny statement at the end.  You're denying `0.0.0.0/0` as well as everything else.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out -- it didn't dawn on me that there is an implicit deny.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add a statement to explicitly allow those prefixes after denying the default-route, so the final prefix-list becomes:

```
ip prefix-list no-default-route seq 5 deny 0.0.0.0/0
ip prefix-list no-default-route seq 10 permit 0.0.0.0/0 le 32
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is correct. Another way of writing the same thing, with just one rule, would be:

```
ip prefix-list no-default-route seq 5 permit 0.0.0.0/0 ge 1
```